# SwiftUI : view automatically moved when simultaneousGesture took effect

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am encountering an issue when I am learning Swift. When I click the button and blur the whole view, the subview automatically move up a bit.

I also find the other similar questions here but all solutions not work for me. I assume maybe there is a mechanism inside when a blur action triggered?

xcode version: Version 13.0 beta 5 (13A5212g)

Anyone know what is going on here ?

[image]
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var select : Int = 1
    @State var ifBlur = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            
            TabView(selection: $select){
                FirstNav().tabItem{
                    Label("aa",systemImage: "folder")
                }.tag(1)
                Text("bb").tabItem{
                    Label("bb",systemImage: "folder")
                }.tag(2)
                Text("cc").tabItem{
                    Label("cc",systemImage: "folder")
                }.tag(3)
            }
            Button(action: {
            }) {
                /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Button")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
            }.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global).onChanged { value in
                ifBlur = true
            }.onEnded { value in
                ifBlur = false
            })
        }.blur(radius: ifBlur ? 2: 0)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
struct FirstNav: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("uu")) {
                    Text("uu")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("ii")) {
                    Text("ii")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("oo")) {
                    Text("oo")
                }
                
            } .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationTitle("").ignoresSafeArea().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("Subtract 1") {
                        }
                        Text("")
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Add 1") {
                        }
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine to me, no issues. Maybe something related to the way how you made your tool bar transparent, because mine is not. Or any other code you haven't mentioned

Comment: @PhilipDukhov It turns out is the version issue. It works fine with xcode installed in apple store but has issue with the beta version downloaded in official website. Thank you for your help.